# Cannot set useState hook value to opposite boolean

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a DatePicker and using useState hook to manage it's visibility. On div click I've added the event listener which changes value, but it didn't work as I expected. It works only the first time, so initial value changes to true, but on second and third clicks this value stays to true and DatePicker stays visible on click.

This is DatePicker

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import OutsideClickHandler from 'react-outside-click-handler';
import { renderInfo, getWeeksForMonth } from './utils';
import {
    renderMonthAndYear,
    handleBack,
    handleNext,
    weekdays,
} from '../../utils';

const DatePicker = ({
    isOpen,
    setIsOpen,
    selected,
    setSelected,
    dayClick,
    dayClass,
}) => {
    const startDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(new Date(startDay));

    const weeks = getWeeksForMonth(current.getMonth(), current.getFullYear());

    function handleClick(date) {
        if (date > startDay) {
            setSelected(date);
            setCurrent(date);
            setIsOpen(false);

            if (dayClick) {
                dayClick(date);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="DatePicker-container">
            <div
                tabIndex="0"
                role="button"
                className="DatePicker-info"
                onKeyPress={e => {
                    if (e.which === 13) {
                        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
                    }
                }}
                onClick={e => {
                    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
                }}
            >
                {renderInfo(selected)}
            </div>
            {isOpen && (
                <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
                    <div className="DatePicker">
                        <div className="DatePicker__header">
                            <span
                                role="button"
                                onClick={() => handleBack(current, setCurrent)}
                                className="triangle triangle--left"
                            />

                            <span className="DatePicker__title">
                                {renderMonthAndYear(current)}
                            </span>

                            <span
                                role="button"
                                onClick={() => handleNext(current, setCurrent)}
                                className="triangle triangle--right"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="DatePicker__weekdays">
                            {weekdays.map(weekday => (
                                <div
                                    key={weekday}
                                    className="DatePicker__weekday"
                                >
                                    {weekday}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        {weeks.map((week, index) => (
                            <div
                                role="row"
                                key={index}
                                className="DatePicker__week"
                            >
                                {week.map((date, index) =>
                                    date ? (
                                        <div
                                            role="cell"
                                            key={index}
                                            onClick={() => handleClick(date)}
                                            className={dayClass(date)}
                                        >
                                            {date.getDate()}
                                        </div>
                                    ) : (
                                        <div
                                            key={index}
                                            className="DatePicker__day--empty"
                                        />
                                    ),
                                )}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </OutsideClickHandler>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DatePicker;
```

DateRangePicker which uses two.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from './DatePicker';
import DatePickerContext from './DatePickerContext';
import './DatePicker.scss';

const DateRangePicker = () => {
    const startDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isSecondOpen, setIsSecondOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Date(startDay));
    const [secondSelected, setSecondSelected] = useState(new Date(startDay));

    function dayClass(date) {
        if (
            selected.getTime() === date.getTime() ||
            (date >= selected && date <= secondSelected)
        ) {
            return 'DatePicker__day DatePicker__day--selected';
        }
        if (date < startDay || date < selected) {
            return 'DatePicker__day DatePicker__day--disabled';
        }
        return 'DatePicker__day';
    }

    function dayClick(date) {
        setSecondSelected(date);
        setIsSecondOpen(true);
    }

    return (
        <DatePickerContext.Provider>
            <div className="DatePicker-wrapper">
                <DatePicker
                    key={1}
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                    setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                    selected={selected}
                    setSelected={setSelected}
                    dayClick={dayClick}
                    dayClass={dayClass}
                />
                <DatePicker
                    key={2}
                    isOpen={isSecondOpen}
                    setIsOpen={setIsSecondOpen}
                    selected={secondSelected}
                    setSelected={setSecondSelected}
                    dayClass={dayClass}
                />
            </div>
        </DatePickerContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default DateRangePicker;
```

Comment: Add `"DatePicker-container"` and `"DatePicker-info"` implementation to your question

Comment: I added keypress event on div, that I was using for click to open and it works, but on mouse click not.

Comment: Here is the full code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

a) It is a good practice to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to make sure to use correct "current" value when the next state is dependent on the previous (== current) state:

```
setIsOpen(currentIsOpen => !currentIsOpen)
```

---

b) It's very hard to reason about the next state when it gets updated by multiple handlers executed for the same event. Following 2 handlers might execute on the same click (the 1st div is "outside"):

```
<div ... onClick={e => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
<OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
```

If `onOutsideClick` executes first, then React re-renders with `isOpen=false`, and then `onClick` executes second, it would set `isOpen=true` as you observe - I don't see how the re-render could happen between, but maybe `OutsideClickHandler` is doing something nefarious or your code is more complicated than in the question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

To enforce only 1 event handler:

```
<OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setIsOpen(false);
}}>
```

Comment: This is of course correct, but it doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work. I created a similar [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/embed/confident-morse-h0939) and it seems to work for me just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @TobiasTengler the question was updated since my answer, at which time it looked as the only possible source of the problem. I have updated my answer to reflect the new information.

Comment: Oh, I got it. So when I click on div it's outside and it changes state and also second click handler changes which sets to same value. Thanks

Comment: For posterity, capturing is enabled by default in https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler/blob/master/src/OutsideClickHandler.jsx, which will cause the stopPropagation call to take no effect.

Comment: @Elmo if I understand it correctly, `useCapture` should work around `stopPropagation` of component's children, but stopping propagation of `onOutsideClick` into the parent should still work.. not enough experience to be 100% sure though

Comment: @Aprillion in which cases not using functional updates could lead to unwanted behaviour? I mean if you have `const [st, setSt] = useState(false)` in which situations `st` could be different than the one passed to the function passed to `setSt`?

Comment: @ZenoDallaValle in any case of a so-called "stale closure", most often inside `useCallback` when ignoring the eslint rule for exhaustive deps, but see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1176601

Comment: but other times it can be useful to remember the closure and NOT rely on the newest value, see e.g. https://epicreact.dev/how-react-uses-closures-to-avoid-bugs/